# Wagtail Forms: How to make preset from field so editor can't change anything?

Tags: forms, wagtail

I'm trying to create a form which will always have the same form fields. I'm following [the documentation](https://docs.wagtail.io/en/v2.11.3/reference/contrib/forms/index.html) but can't seem to find an answer.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is through the Wagtail admin.  First choose `Lock` from the popup menu at the bottom of the page you wish to lock.  Then assign the user to a group for which you want to deny the ability to change the locked page.  By default the Editors group does not allow changing the lock state of a page.  If you can't use that group, then click `Settings` and then `Groups` and then choose the a different group that you have created for the user.  Under the PAGE PERMISSIONS section add a new page permission and choose the page type that you want to deny the user the ability to change.  Make sure `Unlock` is not chosen and save your page permission.  If you set things up this way on your development machine, you'll just have to be sure to do the same thing in production.

Answer (score 0):

I would in that case simple make a django model for it and not use wagtail forms. That way the user can't change it.